# Telegram API doesn't work with username - 400. Bad Request: chat not found

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I received data about myself through API method /getMe

```
    {'ok': True, 'result': {'id': 32484XXXX, 'first_name': 'Name', 'last_name': 'NameN', 'username': '@myname',
                            'type': 'private',
    ...
```

Then I try to send from bot to myself a message with telegram ID and with telegram username.
With ID, everything works fine, but with username it doesn’t work.
What am I doing wrong? How do I send messages with username?

```py
    import requests
    
    telegram_bot_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXX:AAHfPgXkYrqPSakpsxB81UTsYwfmaq9dryY/'
    params_name = {'chat_id': '@myname', 'text': 'test777'}
    params_id = {'chat_id': 32484XXXX, 'text': 'test777'}
    print("ID")
    response = requests.post(telegram_bot_url + 'sendMessage', data=params_id)
    print(response.json())
    print("USERNAME")
    response = requests.post(telegram_bot_url + 'sendMessage', data=params_name)
    print(response.json())
```

and response

```
ID
{'ok': True, 'result': {'message_id': 15, 'from': {'id': 121079XXXX, 'is_bot': True, 'first_name': 'RRRR', 'username': 'RRRR'}, 'chat': {'id': 32484XXXX, 'first_name': 'Name', 'last_name': 'NameN', 'username': 'myname', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1592754152, 'text': 'test777'}}
USERNAME
{'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: chat not found'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely on the BotAPI docs,

> Unique identifier for the target chat or username of the target
> channel (in the format @channelusername)

**Unique identifier** -> which is the chat id  (can be used for any type of chats)

**Username** -> @username can only be used for public channels/groups (no private chats/channels/groups)

Comment: Thanks @R Gautham Ram for your explanations.  If I only know the username, how do I know the ID?

Comment: You cannot get ID with username. You can only get username with ID

Comment: I found @username can be used for supergroups as well